# Angular http get not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm doing some testing with an API in apiary.io and I wanted to call some data from it with Angular, but it doesn't seem to call correctly. It should be pretty simple, so I'm not sure whats wrong:

HTML:

```
<span><a href="network-updates.html">{{user.text}}</a></span>
```

JS:

```
 var MainController = function($scope, $http){

 var usercomplete = function(response){
  $scope.user = response.data;
  };

  $http.get("http://private-abc123-.apiary-mock.com/bus")
.then(usercomplete);

  };
```

JSON:

```
{   
"Header" : "heading",
"text" : "hello"
}
```

Comment: Try parsing your json responce:  `angular.fromJson(response)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me out of the box try: 
(This solution is no longer correct, see update below)

```
var a = angular.module('a', []);

a.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.loadData = function () {
    $http.get("url")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.data = data; //return if success on fetch
        })
        .error(function() {
            $scope.data = "error in fetching data"; //return if error on fetch
        });
    };

    $scope.loadData(); //return loadData function

}]);
```

Update:

```
var a = angular.module('a', []);

a.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.loadData = function () {
    $http.get("url")
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.data = data; //return if success on fetch
        }, function() {
            $scope.data = "error in fetching data"; //return if error on fetch
        });
    };

    $scope.loadData(); //return loadData function

}]);
```

Comment: would you put this within the MainController like I have or have it as a seperate service? does it matter?

Comment: @Whirlwind990 right inside the main controller, ill add my full controller without any filters one sec

Comment: Hm, still no luck. So with your controller, I would be calling the HTML as: {{loadData.text}}  ?

Comment: @Whirlwind990 no it would be `{{data.text}}` unless you are using a repeater where it would be the repeater scope. What console errors do you get when the code is implemented?

Comment: console picked up I was missing the "http://" before loading the external Angular library.... Stupid error but fixed now :P anyway cheers, its all running smooth now, thanks for the controller!

Comment: @Whirlwind990 Cheers! Glad I could help, If you haven't already ran through the official angular tutorial I recommend checking it out: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

Answer (score 1):

I think your response doesn't have a `data` key in it. It should be directly assigned to `$scope.user` like `$scope.user=response`.This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following code snippet to get data from server

```
$http({
    url: "http://private-abc123-.apiary-mock.com/bus", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {user_id: user.id} // If you required params
 }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // You can set scope here 
      $scope.user = data;
 })
```